# Identifying groups have have same values across multiple columns SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, having

I am trying to figure out how to code a SQL query that will identify a group in a table that contains the same value across records in the group over multiple columns.

For example, given the following sample table:

[image: Name Start End Julie]

I am looking to identify in this case the names for whom all trials had the same start and end points. Only James and Frank meet this criteria as per the data. I am not looking to filter and obtain query output that just gives me all groups with either "yes" or "no". I do want the query to output the entire table with the group labeled appropriately. How to go about this?

Below is as far as I got. I do see that when I group by then the groups that show all identical values in the columns of interest do collapse into one group. But if I throw in a new group wherein there are multiple rows (trials) wherein each trial may have the same start and end points but the different trials for the group are not the same points, then actually the group should yield "no" even if each individual trial shows same start and end points.

```
CREATE TABLE Trial
(Name nvarchar(100),
Trial nvarchar(10),
Start nvarchar(100),
[End] nvarchar(100))

INSERT INTO Trial

VALUES
('Julie', 'A', 'Ranch St', 'Ranch St'),
('Julie', 'B', 'Ranch St', 'North Blvd'),
('James', 'A', 'Deer Rd', 'Deer Rd'),
('James', 'B', 'Deer Rd', 'Deer Rd'),
('Emily', 'A', 'Oak St', 'Oak St'),
('Emily', 'B', 'Oak St', 'Elm Rd'),
('Frank', 'A', 'Main Ave', 'Main Ave'),
('Frank', 'B', 'Main Ave', 'Main Ave'),
('Frank', 'C', 'Main Ave', 'Main Ave'),
('Jeff', 'A', 'Main Ave', 'Main Ave'),
('Jeff', 'B', 'Oak St', 'Oak St')

SELECT
    a.[Name]
    ,CASE
    WHEN a.[Start] = a.[END] THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No'
    END AS 'TrialChk'

FROM Trial AS a

GROUP BY a.[Name]
        ,a.[Start]
        ,a.[End]

ORDER BY Name ASC;
```

I don't have the Jeff trial in my sample table above, but Jeff will give "yes" for each trial but since all points are not the same the group's output should be "no".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `case` with window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when min(start) over (partition by name) = max(start) over (partition by name) and
                  min(end) over (partition by name) = max(end) over (partition by name) and
                  start = end
             then 'Yes' else 'No'
        end) as flag
from trial t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=05cb71e8b67d6dfa7cb307a398ed49e7) is a db<>fiddle.

Note:  `end` is a very poor name for a column because it is a SQL keyword.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the windowed function `Row_Number()` as shown below:

```
Create table MyTable (Name varchar(50),
Trial Char(1),
Start Varchar(20),
[End] Varchar(20))

Insert into MyTable Values
('Julie', 'A', 'Ranch St', 'Ranch St'),
('Julie', 'B', 'Ranch St', 'North Blvd'),
('James', 'A', 'Deer Rd', 'Deer Rd'),
('James', 'B', 'Deer Rd', 'Deer Rd')

;with cte as (Select name
,trial
,start
,[End]
,Row_number() Over(Partition By [Start], [End] order by [Start], [End]) as SrNo
From MyTable
)
Select 
   name, trial, start, [End], 'Yes' as [Expected Output] 
from cte where name in ( Select name from cte where SrNo > 1)
union all
Select 
   name, trial, start, [End], 'No' as [Expected Output] 
from cte where name not in (Select name from cte where SrNo > 1)
order by name
```

[Live Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3a7eef596641a5f609b11863039fb8d3)

Answer (score 1):

Check Given Query

```
DECLARE @Counter int  
DECLaRE @CMS_Query varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @total_Row int
DECLARE Cur_1 CURSOR FOR select Name from Trial group by Name

Create Table #MainTrial(
[Name] varchar(MAX),
Trial varchar(MAX),
[Start] varchar(MAX),
[END] varchar(MAX),
[TrialChk] varchar(3)
)
OPEN Cur_1
    DECLARE @Name varchar(MAX)
    FETCH NEXT FROM Cur_1 INTO @Name
        WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
            Begin
                
                SELECT  a.[Name],Trial,Start,[End],CASE WHEN a.[Start] = a.[END] THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No'END AS 'TrialChk' into #Trial1 FROM Trial AS a  where Name = @Name

                select @total_Row = count(*) from #Trial1
                select @Counter = COUNT(*) from #Trial1 where TrialChk = 'Yes'

                IF @total_Row != @Counter
                    BEGIN
                        UPDATE #Trial1 SET TrialChk = 'No' where [Name] = @Name
                    END
                insert into #MainTrial select * from #Trial1
                DROP Table #Trial1
                FETCH NEXT FROM Cur_1 INTO @Name
            END
CLOSE Cur_1
DEALLOCATE Cur_1
select * from #MainTrial
drop table #MainTrial
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you `GROUP BY Name` and count the distinct number of `Start`s and `End`s, just like this query does:

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(DISTINCT Start) start_counter, COUNT(DISTINCT [End]) end_counter
FROM Trial
GROUP BY Name
```

you get theses results:

```
> Name  | start_counter | end_counter
> :---- | ------------: | ----------:
> Emily |             1 |           2
> Frank |             1 |           1
> James |             1 |           1
> Jeff  |             2 |           2
> Julie |             1 |           2
```

So you can join the above query to your table and set `'Yes'` where the 2 counters are both equal to 1, else set `'No'`:

```
SELECT t.*,
  CASE WHEN c.start_counter = 1 AND c.end_counter = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END Result
FROM Trial t 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Name, COUNT(DISTINCT Start) start_counter, COUNT(DISTINCT [End]) end_counter
  FROM Trial
  GROUP BY Name
) c ON c.Name = t.Name
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=639231fc70c5daadf5996faa545549fd).
Results:

```
> Name  | Trial | Start    | End        | Result
> :---- | :---- | :------- | :--------- | :-----
> Emily | A     | Oak St   | Oak St     | No    
> Emily | B     | Oak St   | Elm Rd     | No    
> Frank | A     | Main Ave | Main Ave   | Yes   
> Frank | B     | Main Ave | Main Ave   | Yes   
> Frank | C     | Main Ave | Main Ave   | Yes   
> James | A     | Deer Rd  | Deer Rd    | Yes   
> James | B     | Deer Rd  | Deer Rd    | Yes   
> Jeff  | A     | Main Ave | Main Ave   | No    
> Jeff  | B     | Oak St   | Oak St     | No    
> Julie | A     | Ranch St | Ranch St   | No    
> Julie | B     | Ranch St | North Blvd | No
```